# Why should I use up until or as at in this case?

Tags: sentence-construction

Why is it not possible to write

"it had not arrived **until** yesterday meaning when I checked yesterday,it had not yet arrived.(However I can't check it now so it may have arrived today.)"

You must write :
"It had not arrived **as at** or **up** **until** yesterday."

Comment: It's not idiomatic. _It did not arrive until yesterday_ means that yesterday was when it finally did arrive.

Comment: but you can't explain in english that up to yesterday nothing had come

Comment: may be" it still hadn't arrived yesterday"

Comment: Yes, that would be fine - or simply "It hadn't arrived yesterday", as I suggested in response to your earlier question.

Comment: If I wanted to use the version I would say "It had not arrived **as of** yesterday". Meaning it did not arrive at any time up to and including yesterday, but it may have arrived today, but not necessarily. There is a long discussion about "as at" V "as of" V "as on"in another English language  forum https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/as-at-vs-as-of.537988/ There is the suggestion there may be an element of BrE V AmE involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It had not arrived until yesterday."

Would mean that it did arrive yesterday.

It would also be better written as "It did not arrive until yesterday."

For the meaning you want, a better sentence would be:

"As of yesterday, it had still not arrived."

"As of" implies the last time you checked, where "until" implies it arrived but perhaps not when it was supposed to have.